# Count total occurances when two fields match with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to find the total number of times two fields match in a mongo database. I currently have it working to count the total of one field, but cant figure out how to get it to count when they match. An example of my data is:

| artist   | song   |  played

| artist1  | intro  |  yes

| artist2  | song1 |   yes

| artist1  | intro  |  no

| artist3  | intro  |  yes

| artist1  | intro  |  yes

so currently, i can get it to count the total number of times there is the song title "intro" exists in the database, but i would like for it to be able to differ from artist1's song named "intro" from artist2's song named "intro".

The code i currently have is:

`db.music.aggregate([{$sortByCount: "$song"}])`

which would then output

intro : 4

song1 : 1

But i can't figure out how to change the query to display it as:

artist 1, intro :  3

artist 3, intro :  1

Any help would be appreciated!

Also, is there a way to only count the times where the "played" field is equal to "yes"?

Thanks again!

artist 2, song 1:  1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are your documents:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "artist" : "artist1",
    "song" : "intro",
    "played" : "yes"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "artist" : "artist2",
    "song" : "song1",
    "played" : "yes"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "artist" : "artist1",
    "song" : "intro",
    "played" : "no"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "artist" : "artist3",
    "song" : "intro",
    "played" : "yes"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "artist" : "artist1",
    "song" : "intro",
    "played" : "yes"
}
```

This query will give you the counts for each song by each artist:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{"$match":{"played":"yes"}},
{"$group":{_id:{"song":"$song","artist":"$artist"},"count":{"$sum":1}}},
{"$project":{"song":"$_id.song","artist":"$_id.artist","count":1,"_id":0}}
])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "count" : 1.0,
    "song" : "intro",
    "artist" : "artist3"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "count" : 1.0,
    "song" : "song1",
    "artist" : "artist2"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "count" : 2.0,
    "song" : "intro",
    "artist" : "artist1"
}
```

To get counts only for played songs, just add `{"played":"yes"}` in a match stage like so:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{"$match":{"played":"yes"}},
{"$group":{_id:{"song":"$song","artist":"$artist"},"count":{"$sum":1}}},
{"$project":{"song":"$_id.song","artist":"$_id.artist","count":1,"_id":0}}
])
```

Comment: I'ts sort of hard to explain but what in the situation I'll be using it I wouldn't know the song name, so i was hoping it would be able to count by two columns, if that makes sense. Something where it would return: "Artists 1 - Intro, 3", "Artists 2 - Song 1, 1", "Artists 3 - Intro, 1" Becuase the database i have consists of someones music library play history, where it records every time they play a song. I'm trying to find their most played songs, but since some artists have songs with the same name, I'd need it to check the artist's name when counting. If that makes sense

Comment: @Sam I have updated the answer. Check if this helps.